# Angular 2 - Standalone Component (without layout)

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create "standalone" components, meaning components without the basic app layout?

In my app.component.html I defined the navigation, header and footer. But now I want a login component that uses a different base layout.

My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Left navigation bar -->
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>

    <!-- Main page wrapper -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

        <!-- Top navigation -->
        <app-topnavbar></app-topnavbar>

        <!-- Main view/routes wrapper-->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

And I want the router-outlet of the register and login component to be wrapped in a layout like this:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Main view/routes wrapper-->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is a "different  base layout" related to "component without layout". Components without a layout are directives. But at some places components are required and directives are not supported (`component` parameter in routes,  root component (`bootstrap` parameter in `NgModule`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you currently have a root app component, which contains components for header, navigation and footer, each of them controlling a part of the screen.

The short answer to your questions is: yes, a component does not necessarily need to be included in the root AppComponent. You could simply navigate to your LoginComponent using routing from anywhere in your app.

**EDIT**

You could an additional wrapper for your "basic app layout", say an **BasicAppComponent**, whose template has this structure:

```
<!-- Left navigation bar -->
<app-navigation></app-navigation>

<!-- Main page wrapper -->
<div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

    <!-- Top navigation -->
    <app-topnavbar></app-topnavbar>

    <!-- Main view/routes wrapper-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
<!-- End page wrapper-->
```

Then, in your root app component (**AppComponent**) you will have a structure like this:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Main view/routes wrapper-->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

Additionally, you will build your LoginComponent with the desired structure. The router-outlet from the **AppComponent** will be replaced by either the **BasicAppComponent** or the **LoginComponent**.

Comment: Yes but how would that help me?
I dont just want to navigate to a route, I want a different app layout for some components. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a router : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
Your main component may be  then you will use a constante to define witch component to load...